# T-SQL IF statements in ORDER BY clauses

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sorting

Is there a way I can do something like

```
@sortType

SELECT
    *
FROM
    table
ORDER BY
    -- if sortType == id
    table.Id
    -- else if sortType == date
    table.Date
```

How would that syntax look? Thanks.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There's a gotcha here... you can't mix data types in your case statement, so you need to create different groups of case statements for the different data types.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN @SortType = id THEN table.Id END ASC,
    CASE WHEN @SortType != id THEN table.Date END ASC
```

Related blog post:

http://dirk.net/2006/11/14/dynamic-order-by-with-case-statement-in-sql-server-data-type-issues/

Comment: Would I be able to add DESC|ASC to this?

Comment: Yes, you can add the DESC / ASC to each individual case statement... and if you wanted, ID could be ASC, Date could be DESC... etc...

Comment: I'm giving you the answer, even though I used a mix of your answer and Remus'

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
ORDER BY
case when @sortType = 'id' then
table.Id
else 
table.Date end
```

**Caution: That said, for performance reason it is probably better to split it up or use dynamic sql with sp_executesql**

Comment: I added a blurb, I just wanted to show the technique of using the CASE statement

Answer (score 5):

Don't ever do something like that. The resulted query plan will have to satisfy *both* conditions, since the plan is generic and not tied to a specific runtime value of the @variables. Such plan will miss a lot of possible optimizations. You should explicitly separate the queries:

```
@sortType

if @sortType == id
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    table
  ORDER BY
    table.Id
else if @sortType == date
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    table
  ORDER BY
    table.Date
```

This is the very same issue as trying to implement [dynamic search conditions](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html). The syntactic sugar of using a CASE in the ORDER BY is actually a query optimization blocker.

Comment: Will it hurt optimization terribly?

Comment: For sure it will eliminate possible optimizations. Your query is generic, it uses `*` and has no WHERE clauses so is not a god example. In the real world the optimizations missed can be quite significant. Read the article linked for dynamic search, is quite revealing.

Comment: Yeah that was just for the example, my real query is a lot more complex. I'm just trying to eliminate duplicating all the code.

Comment: To be clear: such a construct will **always** require a sort. Ie. read the whole table, sort it, then return the first row. Splitting the query *may* use an index to satisfy the ORDER BY, thus avoiding the (very expensive) sort. So yes, it will hurt 'terribly'.

Comment: Unfortunately T-SQL is not a friendly language for code reuse, because it is a language that is actually driven by your *data*, not by your T-SQL text: the queries compile to *data access plans* that are dependent on your indexes. Viable solutions are using dynamic SQL (has pros and cons) or using T-SQL code generation (is difficult to bootstratp, but has a lot of pros once implemented).

Answer (score 1):

or just cast the date to an integer...

```
  ... ORDER BY case 
           When @sortType = 'id' Then table.Id 
           Else cast(table.Date As Integer) end
```