# sql order by datetime multiple data

Tags: sql

I'm looking to retrive arrival time or departure time ORDER BY eta OR etd ASC in SQL with differents dates. any ideas please?

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM flights WHERE arrdate = '$date' ORDER BY eta ASC OR WHERE depdate = '$date' ORDER BY etd ASC";
```

it's not working

Comment: Need to tag with `sql` AND a tag for the database that you are using. The `html` and `jquery` tags are irrelevant for this question.

Answer (score 0):

`OR WHERE` is not proper SQL, use `CASE WHEN ... THEN ... END` instead :

```
$sql = "
SELECT * FROM flights 
WHERE arrdate = '$date' OR depdate = '$date'
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN arrdate = '$date' THEN eta END ASC 
CASE WHEN depdate = '$date' THEN etd END ASC
";
```

Read more here : [T-SQL IF statements in ORDER BY clauses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955373/t-sql-if-statements-in-order-by-clauses)

---

As commented, please change the category of your question to **sql** instead of **html** and **jquery**

Answer (score 0):

For the start, I advise you to use different approach while working with SQL.

SQL is **not a procedural language**, it is a different kind of beast.
Keep in mind that SQL is working with sets ... well, most of the time.

As you have 2 data sets - one for arrival and one for departure - let's us try with this:

1. `select FlighID, Company, arrdate as 'flightdate' from flights arrdate = '$date'`
2. `select FlighID, Company, depdate as 'flightdate' from flights depdate = '$date'`

Now, to bring these 2 sets together we'll use UNION:

```
(select FlighID, Company, arrdate as 'flightdate' from flights arrdate = '$date') 
 union all
(select FlighID, Company, depdate as 'flightdate' from flights depdate = '$date')
 order by flightdate asc
```

Pay attention to this:

- I prefer to use 'flightdate' alias because we want to sort output by that field (to stay on the safe side).
- Number of fields in both select statement have to be the same. Fields at the same position must be identical by type.